# Does the number of expired cookies count in MAX nb of cookies allowed per domain

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I know each browser has a certain limit ([see here](https://superuser.com/questions/97625/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-cookie-and-how-many-can-be-stored-in-a-browser-fo)) on the number of cookies allowed by a domain.

Are expired cookies taken into account in this limit?

Ex: let's say chrome limits to 150 cookies per domain.
domain example.com has already set in my computer 140 cookies but which are expired.
Can example.com set 20 more cookies ?

My app is a Deals app.
Each time a user loads a Deal page (example : Deal 'sony mp3), a modal show up showing some **information specific to this deal**. I only load this info when the user loads it the first time. If the user reloads the page, the modal does not show up.

So if/when the user loads the page of another deal (ex: amazon kindle), then I have to create another cookie (called for example cookie_deal_id367).

As a user can maybe go to hundreds of deals every year, I wonder what's the limit. As [it is advised not to go beyond 50](https://superuser.com/questions/97625/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-cookie-and-how-many-can-be-stored-in-a-browser-fo), I wonder if I could play on the expiration and set it to a few days (duration which most deals last for), and this way, IF the number of expired cookies are not taken into account by browsers when they set this 50 cookies limit, I will succeed in what I want to implement.

Open to any ideas to do this, or a better way.

My current code:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    if ($.cookie("cookie_deal"+deal_id) == null) {
      $.cookie('cookie_deal"+deal_id, 'yes', { expires: 720, path: '/' }); // only show  modal once per deal
      $("a.modal:first").trigger("click");       
    }
  });
```

Comment: Expired cookies should automatically get deleted by the browser upon re-visit of the site. Why so many cookies, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: I edited my question to give more context: basically i need to set a cookie per PAGE , in what can be compared to a ecommerce/Deal app. so a user can have hundreds of them...

Comment: btw i am using jquery cookie